# Unable to use SELECT MAX CASE with doctrine

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to create a DQL request using max(case...)
I am using PostgreSQL

Here's a table exemple : (Key values are random)

```
[------TABLE------]
[TYPE |KEY|VALUE  ]
[SWEET|843|WAFFLE ]
[SWEET|258|NUTELLA]
```

And here's what i'd like :

```
[TYPE |DESSERT|SAUCE  ]
[SWEET|GAUFRE |NUTELLA]
```

And here's the (working) SQL i've done :

```
select 
    type,
    max(case when key=843 then valeur end) as dessert,
    max(case when key=258 then valeur end) as sauce
from
    TABLE
group by type
```

But, I can't convert this SQL query to DQL, here's what I tied (not working) :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('table')
->select('table.type')
->addSelect('max(case when table.key=843 then table.value end) as dessert')
->addSelect('max(case when table.key=258 then table.value end) as sauce')
->addGroupBy('table.type')
```

And here's the error I have :

```
 [Syntax Error] Error: Unexpected ')'
```

I tried with and without max, and the DQL generated is correct.
Can you help? Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the ELSE in the case when clause:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('table')
->select('table.type')
->addSelect('max(case when table.key=843 then table.value else null end) as dessert')
->addSelect('max(case when table.key=258 then table.value else null end) as sauce')
->addGroupBy('table.type')
```

Have a nice day

Comment: Probably not related but you have two times the as dessert in your example.

Comment: It seems that it's a common issue on Doctrine :) Have ou tried the following : `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('table')
->select('table.type, max(case when table.key=843 then table.value end) as dessert,max(case when table.key=258 then table.value end) as sauce ')
->addGroupBy('table.type')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get exactly the same error.. haha

Comment: As you may have notice I'm not very familiar with DQL, so my last guess you be: did you try to put the ELSE before the END? like `addSelect('max(case when table.key=843 then table.value else null end) as dessert')` If tris don't work maybe someone else will be more helpful :)

Comment: Thanks a Lot !! @JulHaus ! Please create an answer with the solution ! :)